# Different conclusion from confidence interval and NHST

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, teaching

I would like to ask. I gave to students an example where they test :
$H_0: \pi=0.65$
$Ha: \pi>0.65$
$\hat{p}= 0.76$
$n=50$
Students have to calculate NHST and also confidence interval for proportion.
$Z=\frac{\hat{p}-\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi (1-\pi)}{n}}}$
$Z=1.6307$
$Z_{crit}=Z_{0.95}=1.64$
As can be seen from these calculations we cannot reject the null hypothesis. 
However when we calculate one-sided confidence interval:
$\hat{p}-1.64\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p} (1-\hat{p})}{n}}$
$<0.66;1>$
Based on the test the null hypothesis is rejected; however based on CI we fail to reject the null.

How would you explain to undergraduate students the difference between conclusions?

Comment: Deleted my answer as I had misread your posting.

Comment: This could be a teachable moment about the perils of relying on more significant figures in your calculations than are supported by the assumptions and approximations that underpin it... .